# Stripe: Apply discount to everything BUT subscriptions

Tags: stripe-payments

I operate a small online shop that offers a rotating selection of products (changes frequently). In addition to the products, I offer a subscription. Subscribers earn a discount on product purchases.

I'd like to create a discount that is applied to all products when a subscriber checks out.

I'm using Stripe Checkout.

Currently, I require users to log in on the site, check if they have an active subscription, and then apply a specific `discount`. But this is pretty complex - users have to create an account and login to my site.

**Is there a way to create a coupon applied to product purchases by someone with a subscription?**

One idea I have is to apply a coupon to all subscribers, and raise the subscription price to offset the discount.

Ideally, it would be great to apply a coupon to `goods` or somehow apply it to everything BUT the subscription. But due to how often my products change this would mean updating the coupon with every time the product list updates.

Any other ways to apply a coupon to JUST products (not subscriptions) for a customer with a subscription?

Answer (score 0):

From the sounds of it, you might be adding the [coupon to the Customer](https://stripe.com/docs/api/customers/update#update_customer-coupon). Instead, I'd suggest creating an unlimited usage coupon for your own back-end use. You could include this with every Checkout session ([docs](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/checkout/discounts#creating-coupons), [API](https://stripe.com/docs/api/checkout/sessions/create#create_checkout_session-discounts-coupon)) for one-time product purchases, and simply omit it when creating the [Subscriptions](https://stripe.com/docs/api/subscriptions/create#create_subscription-coupon).

Comment: Close - but I only want customers with an active subscription to have the coupon applied. I currently have a generic coupon, and I apply it to a checkout session - but only if the person logs in and I find a matching active subscription. It works, but ideally they would just have a discount applied on purchases if their email is associated with a subscription.